# What's special about orthogonal contrasts?

Tags: anova, contrasts

In my Design and Analysis class we talked about orthogonal contrasts when it comes to running an ANOVA for one factor of several levels. I understand what it means for two contrasts to be orthogonal. But I'm having trouble understanding why they are important to know. What is special about looking at orthogonal contrasts as opposed to regular ones?